# Is this a valid proof that the $n_r \geq r$ where $(n_r)$ is a subsequence of the sequence $(r)$ which denotes the natural numbers?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

I am currently studying Bartle's *Introduction to Real Analysis* and ran into the proof of Theorem 5.3.2 (Boundedness Theorem) which used the fact that the $r$-th term (r being an element of the natural numbers) of a subsequence of the sequence $(r)$ (which I use to refer to the sequence $(a_n)$ of naturals defined recursively as $a_1 = 1, a_{n+1} = a_n + 1$) is greater than or equal to $r$. I wish to know if the following proof of this fact is valid.

Proof: Let $(n_r)$ be a subsequence of $(r)$ (which I use as I described above) where $n_r, r \in \mathbb{N}$. Then, for $r=1$, $n_r \geq 1$ as $n_r \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}$ is bounded below by $1$, so $n_r \geq r$. Assume the inequality holds for $r = k$. Then, we have $n_k \geq k$. Now we must prove $n_{k+1} \geq k + 1$. Clearly, as $(n_r)$ is strictly increasing because $(r)$ is strictly increasing, $n_{k+1} > n_k \geq k$. The smallest natural number greater than $k$ is, obviously, $k+1$. It follows, then, that $n_{k+1} \geq k + 1$ as $n_{k+1} \in \mathbb{N}$. Hence, the inequality holds for all $r \in \mathbb {N}$.